# vpython not working on windows subsystem for linux

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python3, xming

I am trying to run a simple code in [vpython](https://vpython.org) to check if everything works ok with the module. My code looks like:

```
from vpython import *

scene=canvas()
scene.width=550
scene.height=550
scene.height=580
scene.range=2
ball=sphere(pos=vec(0,0,0),radius=0.8,color=color.orange)
```

I run it using command: `python3 foo.py`. However after that, the program is freezing and when I kill the process I receive the following traceback:

```
   Exception ignored in: <bound method standardAttributes.__del__ of <vpython.vpython.sphere object at 0x7f25192959e8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kuba_unix/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vpython/vpython.py", line 1105, in __del__
    super(standardAttributes, self).__del__()
  File "/home/kuba_unix/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vpython/vpython.py", line 315, in __del__
    cmd = {"cmd": "delete", "idx": self.idx}
AttributeError: 'sphere' object has no attribute 'idx'
```

But I do not know if that is the problem. I am working on Windows 10 and use Windows Subsystem for Linux. For plotting, I use Xming window and set in the bash console the display using `export DISPLAY=:0`.
Until today I did not encounter any problems with plotting (gnuplot and matplotlib work perfectly fine). For additional information, I am using Python 3.5.2 and the version of vpython is ['7.5.0', 'jupyter'] (importing the module does not raise any errors). The result of this program should look like [in this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ks1QB.png).

Comment: Are you using Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: @Biswapriyo No I have a linux bash shell for windows https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

Comment: @Biswapriyo Okay sorry i am using this one then on the second look, just did not know the excact name

Comment: @Biswapriyo i checked if it is working in virtualbox. It works fine but the problem may be that it opens in default browser https://ibb.co/PmcCM13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps required:

- Install packages: `sudo apt install python3 python3-pip`
- Install vpython module: `pip3 install --user vpython`
- Run the python file: `python3 ./foo.py`
- Get the TCP/IP port number from  `netstat -abno` command in Command Prompt. Or use Resource Monitor, TCPView from Sysinternals etc. for GUI. Here is a screenshot from ResMon:

[image: resmon-opend-ports-python]]

- Open any browser in Windows. Type the URL as `localhost:port_number`. For example, in image `localhost:49669`. The first port is for viewing image and later one is to close the connection.

The images is served in a TCP/IP link. So, Xserver is not required here. Although Windows Firewall may not block the connection the port can be opened in firewall (if it is blocked).

Comment: Okay thanks alot for figuring this out! Everything seems working now.